# Flutter - Keyboard keeps on POPPING-UP on iOS inside Chrome & Safari

Tags: ios, flutter, textfield, flutter-web

I'm trying to use a  Flutter `TextField()`  on my Flutter Web App but when running it inside an iOS Browser :

- It keeps on popping up even if i click **outside of TextField** :

[image: GIF iOS WEB KEYBOARD ISSUE]

How do I keep it from popping up?

*Here is a stripped to its minimum code sample to reproduce the issue :*

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: TextField(
              autofocus: false,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              autofillHints: [AutofillHints.email],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      title: 'Flutter Test',
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Same issue, any solution?

Comment: Until this issue get fixed, you can try adding `GestureDetector` in parent,  and in `onTap` remove focus
` FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); `

Comment: I had tested this approach - unfortunatly this trick wouldn't solve this issue - but thks for your answer - also good news the [issue has been fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69850724/12548494)

Answer (score 0):

change TextField to TextFormField.